# Move tags/elements in dom with PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, dom, htmlelements

I have a problem, I'm coding my own helper class in php, but I want to move tags/elements in the DOM (document), for example, I want to move link tag in head and js to bottom in body...

(to do like $("link").appendTo("head").remove(); in jquery)

How can I proceed?
I know exists an DOMDocument API in PHP,
If it's possible to do with it, I would like an example.

Thanks for help.

(sorry for my bad english, i'm french...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created a library that allows you to crawl HTML5 and XML documents just like you do with jQuery.

You can find it [**here**](https://github.com/PHPPowertools/DOM-Query).

It should allow you to do exactly what you want!

Example use:

```
namespace PowerTools;

// Get file content
$htmlcode = file_get_contents( 'https://github.com' );

// Define your DOMCrawler based on file string
$H = new DOM_Query( $htmlcode );

// Define your DOMCrawler based on an existing DOM_Query instance
$H = new DOM_Query( $H->select('body') );

// Passing a string (CSS selector)
$s = $H->select( 'div.foo' );

// Passing an element object (DOM Element)
$s = $H->select( $documentBody );

// Passing a DOM Query object
$s = $H->select( $H->select('p + p') );

// Select the body tag
$body = $H->select('body');

// Combine different classes as one selector to get all site blocks
$siteblocks = $body->select('.site-header, .masthead, .site-body, .site-footer');

// Nest your methods just like you would with jQuery
$siteblocks->select('button')->add('span')->addClass('icon icon-printer');

// Use a lambda function to set the text of all site blocks
$siteblocks->text(function( $i, $val) {
    return $i . " - " . $val->attr('class');
});

// Append the following HTML to all site blocks
$siteblocks->append('<div class="site-center"></div>');

// Use a descendant selector to select the site's footer
$sitefooter = $body->select('.site-footer > .site-center');

// Set some attributes for the site's footer
$sitefooter->attr(array('id' => 'aweeesome', 'data-val' => 'see'));

// Use a lambda function to set the attributes of all site blocks
$siteblocks->attr('data-val', function( $i, $val) {
    return $i . " - " . $val->attr('class') . " - photo by Kelly Clark";
});

// Select the parent of the site's footer
$sitefooterparent = $sitefooter->parent();

// Remove the class of all i-tags within the site's footer's parent
$sitefooterparent->select('i')->removeAttr('class');

// Wrap the site's footer within two nex selectors
$sitefooter->wrap('<section><div class="footer-wrapper"></div></section>');

[...]
```

---

Supported methods :

- [x] [$](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) *(1)*
- [x] [$.parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/)
- [x] [$.parseXML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)
- [x] [$.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/)
- [x] [$selection.add](http://api.jquery.com/add/)
- [x] [$selection.addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)
- [x] [$selection.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/)
- [x] [$selection.append](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [x] [$selection.attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [x] [$selection.before](http://api.jquery.com/before/)
- [x] [$selection.children](http://api.jquery.com/children/)
- [x] [$selection.closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [x] [$selection.contents](http://api.jquery.com/contents/)
- [x] [$selection.detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)
- [x] [$selection.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)
- [x] [$selection.eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)
- [x] [$selection.empty](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) *(2)*
- [x] [$selection.find](http://api.jquery.com/find/)
- [x] [$selection.first](http://api.jquery.com/first/)
- [x] [$selection.get](http://api.jquery.com/get/)
- [x] [$selection.insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/)
- [x] [$selection.insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)
- [x] [$selection.last](http://api.jquery.com/last/)
- [x] [$selection.parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)
- [x] [$selection.parents](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)
- [x] [$selection.remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)
- [x] [$selection.removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)
- [x] [$selection.removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/)
- [x] [$selection.text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [x] [$selection.wrap](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

---

1. *Renamed 'select', for obvious reasons*
2. *Renamed 'void', since 'empty' is a reserved word in PHP*

Comment: Thanks, i'm interresting, that's can be usefull!  but when a say "block system", it means when is set a function setblock("jstobottom"); and a function script("jquery", array("block" => "jstobottom")); i want to replace script() function in dom where is setblock() function. It seems i have saw this in cakephp framework (Helper class with fetch(block) )

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [removeChild](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php) and [appendChild](http://php.net/manual/en/domnode.appendchild.php) to do that

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just, I want too create a "block system" with a function setblock(name), can I create a fake tag ( like <%block name="name"%> ) and replace with regex, in a loop with DOMNode::appendChild() method? That can work?

Comment: Try to write some code so we can check and tell you what is good and what is wrong. Besides - if the answer works, you should vote/accept it for other people to know that it was helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

I will make a block system later, because is too complicated.
Simply, I did this for link tag:

```
/* set view as html string */
ob_start();
require $view;
$html = ob_get_clean();

/* DOM */
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$_head = $dom->getElementsByTagName("head")->item(0);
$links = $dom->getElementsByTagName("link");
foreach($links as $link) {
    $_head->appendChild($link);
}
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
/* render */
echo $html;
```