# Moving stylesheets to the document head during PHP execution

Tags: php

I'm trying to come up with a system where visual components like `foo` or `faa` would be stored in the `/components` folder, and each component would be in its folder with that components files, say `/foo`, and the component files `foo.component.css` and `foo.component.php` inside it.

The `name.component.php` has some `HTML` and a style `<link>` inside, referring to the `name.component.css.` which styles that component. Components are included in page files, such as `index.php`, which gets its `<head>` tag from `head.php`, which is outside the `root`.

The file hierarchy would look like this:

```
├──* head.php
└──* /root
   ├──* index.php
   └──* /components
      ├──* /foo
      │  ├── foo.component.css
      │  └── foo.component.php
      └──* /faa
         ├── faa.component.css
         └── faa.component.php
```

When `index.php` includes a component, its `CSS` will be added outside the `<head>`, which I would like to avoid. Is there a way to move the `CSS` link to the document `<head>` during the `PHP` execution, for example, with a custom function? The `CSS` needs to be moved from the `name.component.php` specifically, so manually adding the `CSS` to the `head.php` won't do.

**File: head.php**

```php
<head>
    <!-- Other non-component stylesheets here; -->
    <!-- Component stylesheets would be moved here during PHP execution; -->
</head>
<body>
```

**File: index.php**

```php
require_once("../head.php");
require_once("coponents/foo.component.php");
```

**File: foo.component.php**

```php
// Can this be moved to the head during execution from this folder?
echo('<link href="/components/foo/foo.component.css" rel="stylesheet">');

// Some HTML elements here...

// Trigger something here that moves the CSS link to the head.php
```

Could buffering be an option here? Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move tags/elements in dom with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314131/move-tags-elements-in-dom-with-php)

Comment: can you use include instead of require? then you simply need a variable in head and fill that variable from, for example, index.php before you include head. And that variable can have whatever strings that need to be included in the "head" file

Comment: Why not use a **proper** templating system that would not print markup in the middle of the execution?

Comment: @NicoHaase, this is purely to experiment with different methods and to learn from them. This is not trying to be optimal in any way but to understand how different solutions could be used. But yes, printing markup in the middle of execution is definitely not the best way to deal with it and was used more as an example to understand my issue. My bad. The answer Salketer gave is more what I had in my mind.

Comment: @NicoHaase Why is it a problem to print markup in the middle of the execution?

Comment: "Why is it a problem to print markup in the middle of the execution" - because you cannot modify the order of that markup properly. If you print a closing `</head>` in one file and want to add something to the head in another file, how would you do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should your component really define the css with an echo?

Your index.php could insert it, if you followed a naming convention. The problem you'll see is when you have more complexe things to do...

The way I'd do it is to create some sort of manifest for your component. You'd have a class that would list the required css files, javascript files (why not) and template files. Your index.php could easily run through the definition and include at the proper places.

```
// File foo.manifest.php
class FooComponent implements Component{
    public $stylesheets = ['foo.component.css'];
    public $javascripts= ['foo.component.js'];
    public $dependsOn = []; // You could set dependencies here so other components are loaded if needed.
    public $template = 'foo.component.php';
}
```

You index would load up the class, and loop through its stylesheets to echo them at the right place.

```
$components = [new Foo(),new Faa()];
foreach($components as $component){
   foreach($component->stylesheet as $stylesheet){
      echo ('<link href="'.$stylesheet.'" rel="stylesheet">');
   }
}
require_once("../head.php");

foreach($components as $component){
   require_once($component->template); 
}
```

You'll have to figure out how to play with the paths tough, either your manifest declares them relative to the index.php or you find a way to know the file from where the manifest class comes from so you can make a relative path from it, unfortunately I'm not very good at PHP for this...

Comment: I didn't think about making a component class to handle it all. Thank you, this should work! Very much appreciated!

Comment: I've used a class because it allows to fit on an interface, but this could be a simple hashmap too or anything...

Answer (score 0):

What I am doing in the website I am working on now is to have a single *head.php* file which I bring into the PHP files for the various pages on my site. Sometimes a particular PHP file for one of the pages may require a different JS file or CSS file. So, I have `<?= $headEls ?>` inside the head element in *head.php*.

Now, inside one of the PHP files for the pages I can assign a value to `$headEls` which is just a string for any *script* or *link* elements that may be required.

One problem is that with the above system you have to assign a value to `$headEls` inside every PHP file (even if you just make it an empty string) or you get an error trying to access an undefined variable. In order to get round that I put the following line inside *head.php* before trying to access `$headEls`: The line is `$headEls = isset($headEls) ? $headEls : '';`. So now I only have to assign a value to `$headEls` if I actually have a CSS or JS file(s) I want to bring into it.

I am sure that better systems can be thought of but it does work and I do not want to use a framework which solves all these problems plus ones I have never thought about but involves 1000s of files on my server and my local machine.